# Culture changing in a way I don't like, anything I can do?

Tags: resignation, company-culture, stress, culture

I have worked as a software developer for a company for 5  years, they were a small start up when I joined and the emphasis was on the quality of your output, that is how you were judged as an employee and I always got good feedback on my work, complete projects on time etc

They were bought by a larger company 2 years ago and the past 18 months the culture has been shifting in such a way that it is having a negative impact on my morale and happiness. The biggest negative for me is the introduction of two systems to track employee's time. The first system tracks time allocated to specific tasks and the second system tracks the time you are in the office.

This implies to me they don't trust their employees as professionals and just encourages presenteeism and box ticking. The non-software parts of the business, mainly the admin side, have embraced this change. I suppose it makes things easier for them.

I can understand the need to track time against issues to bill customers but we have to log 8 hours a day, every day, even when the time isn't billable to anyone. It is getting to the point where internal bookkeeping seems to be valued more than the actual quality of your work. I have raised it with my manager and he assures me that it is not done because they don't trust their employees but I find it hard to believe that because he has no alternative business reason or any other justification for it.

I am pretty resentful of the situation. I feel that if I wanted to punch in and out of work and be treated like a child I could have worked at a factory. And while I genuinely like the people I work with if I have to put up with this sort of culture I may as well go work for another company that would pay me more for doing so.

Realistically is there anything I can do to push back against this, or is my best option to just leave ?

Comment: Does your employement contract state anything regarding working hours?  It's pretty hard to push back against a company for enforcing the contract that you signed.

Comment: `bought by a larger company 2 years ago and the past 18 months the culture has been shifting in such a way that it is having a negative impact on my moral and happiness. The biggest negative for me is the introduction of two systems to track employee's time` - hmm, sounds like you either put up or.. well, yea  . Mergers can be a little stressful no doubt Good luck : )

Comment: I think it is amusing that you think they want to treat you like a child because you are the one who is acting like one. Timesheets are a legitmate business need. They need to unmderstand who is spending how much time on what to determine future manpower needs, to rearrange workload, to charge customers, etc. And yes to prevent slackers from not working the hours they are paid to work. You think you are too good to do them but you aren't .   And you are letting something that takes a few minutes a day ruin your morale when you like the work and the people? Really it is time to grow up.

Comment: @HLGEM: Why do you think that time sheets actually work for that purpose? While there is a legitimate business need to know what's going on it's entirely unclear whether do time sheets do anything useful especially in more creative environments. See for example https://hbr.org/2015/01/workers-are-bad-at-filling-out-timesheets-and-it-costs-billions-a-day

Comment: @Hilmar - I'm guessing it depends on the environment like you say. In  creative environments it definitely sounds funny to use time sheet

Comment: @HLGEM, the first time system mentioned by the OP sounds normal enough, but the second time system "tracks the time you are in the office." In my experience, the former is common, but systems like the latter are unusual in a software development environment. Most software developers would be a little indignant, I think, if they had to record the time they arrive and leave the office. If you're not performing well, you would expect that level of scrutiny, but not if you're a good performer.

Comment: This type of system is common in large organizations, I have never had a job where I didn't have to do this. Software is not some special thing that is exempt from what the rest of the company has to do. It is silly to waste thought or energy on such things. Of course if you are not putting in 40 hour weeks, then it is a problem. Salaried doesn't mean I can come and go as you please, it means you don't get paid overtime and there is a limited amount of slack to make up for the unpaid overtime you do work.

Comment: Do you fill out a timesheet regarding your time in the building or is it part of badging in/out of the building?  My employer keeps track of every person in/out of the building, it's part of the security system. IT deos indirectly track how much time I am in the building, but it also helps tell me who is in or out, before I go looking for them.  In case of an emergency, it would also help us confirm that everyone got out.

Comment: Are you being evaluated based on the amount of time in the building?

Comment: Five years is a long time to spend in one place as a developer. The majority of senior developers I know - myself included - have never spent that long in one place. If you're really not finding your work environment enjoyable any more, there's really no good reason not to be looking for an alternative.

Comment: @HLGEM actually in the USA at least, too fine a point on the hours an employee is working can put overtime exemption at risk.  If they start treating you too much like an hourly employee, it can trigger a reclassification.  "The regs state that the amount of money a salaried employee earns can’t be dependent on the number of days or hours he or she works." http://www.hrmorning.com/docking-pay-exempt-employees/  Of course there are more nuances but salaried literally means pay is not based on number of hours worked.

Comment: @HLGEM It is unusual in software development to track anything except billable hours, which I don't actually have a problem with. The issue is we are expected to track every minute as well as our attendance in the office. I'm a professional, I expected to be trusted to carry out my duties and be judged on my output. Management have publicly complained that they have lost the start up style productivity from every software development office they have acquired, they seen unable to connect the did. Dots.

Comment: @Andy Right, the IRS does not take this sort of thing lightly. But then, how does anyone know how much time anyone really works? It is like telling the company that they must wear a blindfold, or start treating everyone as hourly. The distinction of part-time and full-time is getting very sticky also. Eventually, we will all just be contractors, whether working as Engineers or burger flippers, and that will be the end of it.

Comment: @nocomprende The point of salary is that it does not matter how many hours the employee works.  They are paid for the results they produce, not the hours they put in.  The distinction between part-time and FT is not sticky at all; its very clearly defined in law.  And there are also laws about how employees are classified.  Uber is facing a lawsuit which contents its drivers are not in fact contractors (as Uber says), but actual FT employees.  Fast food workers are the same; they cannot be arbitrarily classified as contractors or salary.

Comment: @nocomprende .. as to be paid salary AND exempt from overtime (those are to distinct issues, BTW) the salary must be a certain minimum; something like $35K / year, and of course, not counting hours is part of it as well.  The law (in the US at least) is pretty clear.  The current Uber lawsuit is to resolve as a matter of fact if the Uber drivers are contractors or FT; the court will examine the facts and basically go down a checklist to rule.

Comment: @Andy my point that "everyone will by contractors eventually" was not so much about how the law stands and hours and pay and so on. The point was that over time we have seen that companies offer less in the way of benefits beyond pay: pensions have changed to personally managed retirement, healthcare is moving to individual status, taxation can become individual (have you ever run a small business?), so our "older brother" the Employer will not be providing all these things, and we must eventually take on all this responsibility ourselves. I see this as inevitable for business to stay afloat.

Comment: Why must everyone be so concrete and literal in their arguments here? It is the one thing that bothers me most about SE. If we are intelligent, cannot we reason in abstraction? Are we all Pharisees or something?

Comment: @nocomprende I see what you were saying now.  I thought you were referring to the trend of companies actually attempting to say their FT employees are contractors; there have been a number of lawsuits in the past few years which revolve around that.

Comment: @Andy yes, and hours are reduced to keep part-time people below the new lower FT requirements. Employers get more value out of two PT employees. In some fields like programming, one can do lots of little projects and not be employed at all. Headlight of the oncoming train, or light at the end of the tunnel? Depends on your smarts and opportunities, but it is too complex for most people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Realistically is there anything I can do to push back against this, or
>   is my best option to just leave ?

I've experienced this exact scenario three times - it's almost eerily familiar.

- Worked for a startup
- Acquired by a larger company having a very different culture
- Two different time tracking systems - work hours, and project hours
- Very unhappy, for this and many other reasons

Unfortunately, I don't have anything very positive to offer you. Each of my situations ended with me giving up on my attempts to change the larger corporate culture, and eventually leaving.

I look at it this way - this is not the work environment you signed up for. You decided to join a startup because at least some significant aspects of their culture appealed to you. Now you work for a different kind of company, with a different culture. I'd bet that if you were on the market, this isn't the kind of company you'd consider interviewing with.

You might decide to stick around a while to see if anything changes. One thing that happens frequently in larger companies is reorgs. Every large company I worked for had rather frequent reorgs (unfortunately, not all of them for the better).

But barring that, it sounds like you should either learn to live with the big-company culture or seek out a company that more closely fits your idea of a good company culture. I always suggest waiting until you've landed your next job before quitting your current job.

> Culture changing in a way I don't like, anything I can do?

Unless you are a C-Level executive, or at least a General Manager of your division, I don't think there's much you can do.

Comment: I didn't think there was anything I could do, just hoping I guess. I really enjoy working with the people there, my boss is great but I think it is time to move on. Thanks for the answer, it helped me make up my mind.

Answer (score 4):

I've lived through this twice and seen it once more (I joined the company after the acquisition but it was still fresh in everyone's minds).  There are two categories of culture issues: the ones that are more about how teams do their work and peers interact, which you can affect, and the ones that are more about bureaucracy, which you generally can't.  Time-tracking fits into the latter category.

A larger company that already had procedures in place bought your company.  They, being the acquirer and the larger party, are not going to change how they operate -- not across the board, and not by making an exception for you.  Large companies operate by making operations as consistent across the organization as possible.  Everybody will use the same time-tracking system, for example, whether you directly bill customers or are internal support.  Because people who bill customers need to track the number of hours, so do you.  And, more grimly, because some people slack off and don't work a full week, you all need to do so (documentably).

It is very unlikely that you can do anything about the timesheets.  What you *can* do is talk with your direct management (assuming it's your pre-acquisition manager) about informal arrangements.  For example, the policy may require you to work 40 hours each and every week; if you put in a ton of extra time last week to meet a deadline, though, your manager might be fine with you working less this week and adjusting the bookkeeping.  Or he might be a stickler; you won't know until you ask.

Your whole company is presumably facing this change, and you're unlikely to be the only one who's upset.  Before you give up and leave, it's worth chatting with your peers and friendly managers about ways to mitigate the morale damage.

All that said, companies do change over time, and down the road you'll probably either get used to this or go elsewhere.  As you continue to hire people, the proportion of people who remember the "old days" will go down and there will be less pressure to preserve what you had.  New employees will have only ever known the current system.  But you can probably put this off for a few years if your coworkers feel as you do.

Answer (score 0):

Timesheets is a very standard practice in professional organizations, and moreso in larger ones where the owner isn't directly involved with every single employee.  Lawyers fill out timesheets.  Engineers fill out timesheets (actual engineers, not programmers).  Pretty much every type of consultant fills out timesheets.

As mentioned, there are a variety of business needs to doing it.  First and foremost, if your company works for clients, it's the best way of knowing how many billable hours to charge them.  Even if you only work on one project for weeks at a time, it's much easier for you to fill out your timesheet to that effect instead of having your supervisor do it for you and everyone else they manage.  It's actually giving you *more* responsibility.

Comment: True, but the OP said "The first system tracks time allocated to specific tasks and the second system tracks the time you are in the office." In my experience, the former is common, but systems like the latter are unusual in a software development environment.

Comment: @mhwombat the problem is, if your hours don't add up to 40+, someone will wonder, "What were they doing, or not doing, in those missing hours?" Then the law and the system conspire to create an unsolvable problem. I used to record time on code review or some other non-billable task, which was most of my time when I was in R&D (projects developed for no particular client). Then they said that R&D was not "profitable"... Umm?